# How to find most recent database record with multiple different components

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a database that takes in score predictions.

I've noticed when I try to pull the most recent submission, I'll occasionally pull the wrong components. The point of this query is to select out the most recent submission, for each user, for each match_num.

Example:

- Mike predicts Packers 20, Jets 14 at 8:00 PM
- Mike predicts Packers 20, Jets 10 at 8:01 PM

Need to always pull the most recent (i.e. 8:01 PM) query for Mike.

Just for thoroughness, the match_num value is just a uniqueID for the Packers vs. Jets game. And... I have the date's stripped of specialchars in my db, so they are infact larger integers as time moves forward, per regular practice.

Here's my code:

```
select DISTINCT
    max(t1.date) AS time_1,
    t1.username,
    t1.match_num,
    t1.a_score,
    t1.b_score
from 
    user_scores_raw t1
    inner join (
        select max(date) as maxdate, username
        from user_scores_raw
        group by username, match_num
    ) t2
    on t1.username = t2.username
    and t1.date = t2.maxdate
GROUP BY username, match_num
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The point of this query is to select out the most recent submission, for each user, for each match_num.

You seem to be missing a join condition on `match_num`. Also, there is no point aggregating the outer query, as well as using `DISTINCT`.

```
select 
    t1.date AS time_1,
    t1.username,
    t1.match_num,
    t1.a_score,
    t1.b_score
from 
    user_scores_raw t1
    inner join (
        select max(date) as maxdate, username, match_num
        from user_scores_raw
        group by username, match_num
    ) t2
    on t1.username = t2.username
    and t1.date = t2.maxdate
    and t1.match_num = t2.match_num
```

Note: if you are using MySQL 8.0, your query can be simplified by using window functions. Consider:

```
SELECT *
FROM (
    SELECT
        `date`
        username,
        match_num,
        a_score,
        b_score,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY username, match_num ORDER BY `date` DESC)
    FROM user_scores_raw
) x WHERE rn = 1
```

Answer (score -1):

Based on your provided SQL you're not comparing time_1 to your maxdate value from t2.